# How did all my email addresses get set to On Hold?

Tags: civimail

On Jan 25 I emailed my constituency (120) and had no bounces. On Feb 3 I sent another email and got 100% bounces (ditto for 2 emails after that). Just realized this today.

Somehow EVERYONE was set to On Hold. Any idea why this might have happened?

Comment: when you look at the mailing report what is the syntax it gives for the bounce reason?

Comment: Where do I find the syntax for the bounce? All I find in a Report named Email Bounces is Bounce Type and the response, 978 times, is syntax.

Comment: In the Mailing report itself, the link from Bounces should take you to civicrm/mailing/report/event?reset=1&mid=xxxx&event=bounce and you should see Bounce Reason. you can also add this field on the Bounce report at civicrm/report/instance/26?reset=1 (though that ID may vary on your version)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for many reason

- Mailing template which you are sending is too big (too big picture)
- your server might be busy. So, the job didn't reach the mailing server

To confirm the same - Try removing on hold flag from all the contact and try to send a simple text message - it should work

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: if the job didn't reach the mailing server would the contacts actually be put On Hold?

Comment: I have seen this issue - when sending email from CiviCRM all the contact had on-hold but nothing was reported in sparkpost - Because of server issue (Server was busy) - Still I did see all the contact had changed to On-hold

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing this after webform registration. Recently I noticed that an important proportion of the new members are defined as 'on hold'. I've checked the addresses and all of them look correct. This is a bit strange.

Comment: This issue continues, rendering civiMail useless. There is nothing wrong with my server and the other comments have not been helpful.